# Fill Tree View dynamically from SQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, treeview

Please help me to populate a tree view from SQL database dynamically.  I have two table formats given in the picture below and I want to fill the tree view from database accordingly. I searched on other resource sites also but didn't find the solution what I am looking for.

Please view given image:

[image: The tree view I want to create]

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No is this my project part, Please help,

Comment: What framework are you using?  [tag:winforms]?  [tag:wpf]?  Or something else?  Also, are you just asking about to populate a tree view, or asking how to run a query, get the results, and then populate the tree view?  If so, that question is too broad for stack overflow.  Try to break your question down into discrete steps, and ask about each one.

Comment: I was using entity framwork i want how to add databse data to tree view

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have two choices

You either run a JOIN which will create a result from the db where the department name is repeated over and over, and the sub department name is unique; you then loop over this result set row by row with a logic of:

- try and retrieve the tree node with the department name X
- if it failed because there was no tree node X add a new tree node X to the children of the root node
- now there certainly is a node for department X, either new or already existing: add the child sub department to the node

---

Or, you run two loops

- Query the departments and start a loop over the results
- create a node for the current department row
- query the database for the sub departments of this current department
- start another loop that adds the sub departments just queries as children of the current department node

---

In either case you'll need to query a db, so get that part working. Entity Framework will help if you want to use it

Also, look into adding nodes to a tree view and get familiar with it - don't need a db for this, just code it up by hand manually adding nodes for practice